# iPhone holiday calendar off by 1 day

Tags: iphone, calendar, timezone

The built-in holiday calendar on my iPhone 8 running iOS 12.4.1 is off by one day. For example, it shows New Year's Eve on December 30 and not on December 31.

So far I tried to :

- Enable automatic date & time in `Settings > General > Date & Time > Set Automatically = "On"`
- Desable the time zone override in `Settings > Calendar> Time Zone Override = "Off"`
- Reset the iPhone
- Switching off automatic date & time and entering my time zone then switching back to automatic
- Switching off Location Services and GPS in `Settings > Privacy > Location Services.` then switching back on

What could I do next ?

Note: My personal calendar doesn't have the issue nor my MBP's calendar ; but  I added another location holiday and it have the same issue...

Comment: Upgrading to iOS 13.2.3 fixed the issue

Answer (score 1):

What if you unsubscribe from the holiday calendar and then set the time zone on your phone to be exactly what you want.

Then power cycle it (to be sure all the apps know and can read the correct zone).

When you subscribe back to the calendar - pay attention if there are advanced options on time zone.

We might need to know the exact subscription URL you're using and which account backs this calendar. iOS calendars can be stores in Exchange, O365, google, iCloud or other third and first party solutions or not sync at all. Depending on your specific set up, the time zone settings might not even be on your phone if you're syncing down from a cloud service.

Comment: The holiday calendar is the one that came with the iPhone, I never subscribe to it in the first place... I'm not able (or can't figure it out) to delete it. It's enable in my iCloud setting, but not sure if I'm syncing down from it

Comment: I agree it sounds like a time zone issue

Comment: But if the issue would be the time zone, why my personal calendar is not messed up as well ? Also, even if the time zone is wrong, new year's eve should always be december 31...

Comment: @EddGrowl Time is hard for programmers to test. this is just how I would triage and troubleshoot. I don't have a way to reproduce this so I could be wrong entirely.

Comment: @EddGrowl I agree that it's likely a Time Zone issue. If something is describing New Year's Eve as 31st Dec 00:00 GMT to 23:59 GMT, then that starts on 30th Dec 23:00 for a Time Zone one hour behind. This is a known problem that has cropped up over the years. A quick Google shows the solution is usually turning settings off and on, and resetting the phone, as bmike suggests.

Comment: I did turned settings off and on, and resetting the phone... But my point is, when traveling to another time zone location, New Year's Eve should still be on december 31 as calendar sync with your location, right ? Furthermore, I added another location holiday and it have the same issue...