# iPhone Calendar off by a day

Tags: iphone, calendar

Situation: a client is in Mexico currently. On his iPhone calendar, every event is off by a day. If a new event is created on a specific day it will put it in the calendar one day behind what you set. All synchronized calendars are also off by a day.

Upon searching on Ask Different I came across [This post](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/375069/iphone-holiday-calendar-off-by-1-day)

Its mostly things I have tried already as I suspect that it has something to do with the cellular service in Mexico and time zones.

There are 2 other devices that he has with him, a iPad, and a MacBook. Those 3 devices are displaying the correct calendar information and reflect correctly across those devices. Once the calendar event is synched with his iPhone, the date is set back a day.

What I have done:

- Turned off automatic time zones and set the date and time manually
- Removed all calendar events and added them back
- Created new calender events
- Set time zone manually
- Set time zone automatically

It's important that we can't reset the iPhone while on vacation. Does anyone have any experience with how to fix this?

Comment: Does the iPhone itself show the correct day, or is it only Calendar events?

Comment: yes the iphone shows the correct date. @icon